# Can you store a class type in a variable?

Tags: java

I am not too familiar with Java. I have no idea what I am trying to do makes sense.

I have a situation where I have several methods (named say getData()) that do the same operation on an instance of class. Everything these methods do is the same except instance types (named say classX, classY, classZ below) which would be different.  These classes are all root level and do not have a common parent class.  The classes are existing code that I cannot modify.

To implement these methods I have to write a separate class for each like the following:

```
public class classA {
    String tableName = "T1";
    public classX getData () {
        classX cls = fetchFromDB(tableName);
        return cls;
    }
}

public class classB {
    String tableName = "T2";
    public classY getData () {
        classY cls = fetchFromDB(tableName);
        return cls;
    }
}

public class classC {
    String tableName = "T3";
    public classZ getData () {
        classZ cls = fetchFromDB(tableName);
        return cls;
    }
}
```

With the above I have to repeat a lot of code with the getData() methods.  I was trying to see if something like the following where the class type can be stored in a variable would work.  I have no idea what 'ClassType' would be. Would this be possible in Java?

```
public class Root {
    ClassType classType = null;
    String tableName = null;
    public classType getData () {
        classType cls = fetchFromDB(tableName);
        return cls;
    }
}

public class classA extends Root {
    String tableName = "T1";
    ClassType classType = ClassX;
}

public class classB extends Root {
    String tableName = "T2";
    ClassType classType = ClassY;
}

public class classC extends Root {
    String tableName = "T3";
    ClassType classType = ClassZ;
}
```

Then I can call

```
classX cls = classA.getData();
classY cls = classB.getData ();
classZ cls = classC.getData();
```

(The code samples above is just to give an idea and not necessarily complete/accurate.)

Or is there any way to achieve this and not have to repeat code?

Comment: In general, the best way to do this isn't to store the class type, but to store a method reference: `Function<ClassT, T> dataGetter = ClassA::getData`.

Comment: Class X, Y and Z need to all extend some sort of Data class if you want the others to be children as well to re-use teh code

Comment: @LouisWasserman Could you please explain a bit more in detail with an example? Or point me to a link.

Comment: @BenjaminW. Like I said these are existing classes that I cannot modify

Comment: It looks like you are creating DAOs (Data Access Object) for your data classes.  You should be able to define a base class that does the bulk of the work with concrete extensions that implement some abstract methods (e.g. `getTableName()`) and use generics to identify the return type.

Comment: Please be more concrete with your example. What do the (databse-)tables store, what is common and shared (e.g. connection, `fetch` method, etc.) ? What are you trying to implement - the [DAO pattern](https://www.baeldung.com/java-dao-pattern) ?

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use generics:

```
public class Root<T> {

    String tableName = null;
    Class<T> classType = null;

    public Root(String tableName, Class<T> classType) {
        this.tableName = tableName;
        this.classType = classType;
    }

    public T getData () {
        return fetchFromDB(tableName, classType);
    }

    private T fetchFromDB(String name, Class<T> classType) {
       // classType might not be necessary, it depends what you need
       // to do in this method
       ...
    }
}

public class ClassA extends Root<ClassX> {
    public ClassA() {
       super("T1", ClassX.class);
    }
}

public class ClassB extends Root<ClassY> {
    public ClassB() {
       super("T2", ClassY.class);
    }
}

public class ClassC extends Root<ClassZ> {
    public ClassC() {
       super("T3", ClassZ.class);
    }
}
```

It might be  possible to refactor the code based on the exact usecase (I don't know what `fetchFromDB` looks like).